# SQL query took too long to execute in server

Tags: mysql

Last week i ran my sql query in server and it took one day to finish the query.
but when i tried in localhost, it runs fast.

```
SET @curr_date = CURDATE();

SELECT s.created_date as 'date', 'registrasi_h2h' as transaction , s.no_ecash as nomor_ecash, IFNULL(s.partner_id,'') as partner_id
FROM subscription_hist s
WHERE DATE(s.created_date) = @curr_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER BY s.created_date ASC;
```

i've been trying to find the problem for the whole week, but i can't find the solution for this.

Comment: How large is the `subscription_hint` table, and how many other queries might have been concurrently executing while yours was also?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen quite a lot i think, i can't check it because i don't have permission for it. i just make the queries. but it's the only query that executed at that time.

Comment: could be the 'order by'? i had similar problem yesterday, and 'order by' caused that

Answer (score 1):

The only advice I can offer you is to try to add an index which can be used in the `WHERE` clause to speed things up.  And since you are really looking for records from a specific day, an index on `created_date` could help substantially.

```
ALTER TABLE subscription_hist ADD INDEX c_date_idx (created_date)
```

MySQL doesn't support function indices, so using `DATE(created_date)` in your `WHERE` clause probably won't be able to take advantage of the index.  But if `created_date` already be a datetime column, then I don't even see any point in wrapping it with `DATE()`.  Just use that column directly, e.g. something like this:

```
SELECT
    created_date AS `date`,
    'registrasi_h2h' AS transaction,
    no_ecash AS nomor_ecash,
    IFNULL(partner_id, '') AS partner_id
FROM subscription_hist
WHERE created_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
      created_date < CURDATE()
ORDER BY created_date ASC;
```

Follow the link below for a demo showing that the date logic works correctly.

## Rextester

Comment: i use date() because created_date is datetime and i want only get the date only.